# How to check type of Internet connection ios

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to use reachability class to detect valid internet connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195012/how-to-use-reachability-class-to-detect-valid-internet-connection) 
>   [Iphone detect 3g or wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/iphone-detect-3g-or-wifi)

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a user's iOS device is connecting to the Internet via cellular (3G/[EDGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Data_Rates_for_GSM_Evolution)) vs. using a Wi-Fi connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Reachability library](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/).