# are there network connectivity callbacks for ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I want to block my app's ui when there is no network connectivity.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623272/how-to-use-scnetworkreachability-in-swift/25623647#25623647) about checking network connectivity.

Is there a way to register for a listener with callback `"onNetworkLost()"`, `"onNetworkAvailable()"`?  Instead of creating my own periodic task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reachability class to get notification when network status has changed. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html for documentation as well as sample code on integrating Reachability. It gives you `kReachabilityChangedNotification` notification which is broadcasted when network status has changed. Once you get the notification you can check whether network is available or not.

You can also refer this [How to use reachability class to detect valid internet connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195012/how-to-use-reachability-class-to-detect-valid-internet-connection)